# How to plot no bar for NA in barplot R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, na

How can we show an empty bar for `NA` when using the base R `barplot` function? In `ggplot2` this will be done like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`position_stack()`).
```

[image]

As we can see the `NA` is empty for group A. If we do the same using `barplot` at first, it won't show the group with `NA`:

```r
df = data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:5],
                value = c(NA, 1, 4, 3, 2))
barplot(value ~ group, data = df)
```

[image]

We could replace the `NA` by 0, but this will still show a really small bar and not an empty one like for ggplot:

```r
df[is.na(df)] = 0
barplot(value ~ group, data = df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So how can we show an empty bar for the group with NA like in ggplot?

---

**Data used**:

```
df = data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:5],
                value = c(NA, 1, 4, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the argument `na.action` with `"na.pass"` like this:

```r
barplot(value ~ group, data = df, na.action = "na.pass")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the bar is now empty for group A like in ggplot.

Comment: +1 for sharing your insights, however those empty bars scare me and rather look like a misprint or coding mistake, but that may be a matter of opinion.